# Using libjpeg-turbo with PHP

Tags: php, image, image-processing, server

I have correctly installed the package library libjpeg-turbo on my server, how i can use it with PHP scripts?

I need to build a demo tester for uploading images.
In short words, the user upload an image and I display the original image size, then my script compress and output the final compressed image with the final size result of compression.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: I don't need to explain because my question is general, how i can use the library with php? For example this site: https://compressor.io/compress use the same system that i want to create.